# Change to Virtual Console 2-4 on target system via PuTTY and screen

Tags: putty, tmux, gnu-screen

I am trying to figure out how to change to Virtual Consoles 2-4 on a target system using PuTTY and screen.  I have read the screen man pages and the replies [here](https://superuser.com/questions/311256/sending-change-virtual-console-command-in-putty),
but I still can't figure it out.  These are systems booting off of a network image that I don't have control over, so I can't just install tmux, which seems to be the "best" option.

Is there a simple screen command I can use to switch to / see / control the virtual consoles on my systems? I need real examples, as the ones I've seen in the man page and other searches have not been helpful.  I need to see the actual Virtual Consoles that already exist on the target, not just create new ones via "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>" in PuTTY, as these systems have processes running on different consoles I need to be able to see and control.

Comment: Does `Ctrl+A` `"` not work? How about `screen -ls` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [linked page](https://superuser.com/questions/311256/sending-change-virtual-console-command-in-putty) notes that you cannot connect to different virtual consoles using ssh, and recommends using screen or tmux (which are different).

If you had a screen or tmux session running on the remote machine, you could attach to *that* and see what is running in each of the session's "windows".

Without that, the most you could do would be to read the standard-output device for the process that you want to inspect.  But as noted in *[Why can't I `tail -f /proc/$pid/fd/1`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/why-cant-i-tail-f-proc-pid-fd-1)*, it is not really that simple.